# mySQL Creating a table is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, web

Ok, This is probably a simple fix, but I am failing to see why it continues to display this instead of just making the simple table in SQL

Displays this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TABLE' (T_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Addyr/tableadd.php on line 10

Here is php I am using (I don't see the problem?!?) -->

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","search_matrix");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    CREATE TABLE 
    web_matrix
    (
    _title varchar(30),
    desc varchar(80),
    url varchar(255),
    suburls varchar(255)
    );
?>
```

Comment: You can't just chuck a MySQL statement in the middle of your PHP script and expect it to work... Which book are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- One of the problems with your code is, `desc` is a MySQL reserved word

  - **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

wrap it in backticks

```
`desc` varchar(80),
```

or choose another word for it.

Using reserved words are discouraged to be used, as much as possible.

***Edit:***

The other is:

- The error stems from you not using the proper syntax in order to create the table, as intended.

To create your table, you need to use the following:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE `web_matrix`(
`_title` varchar(30),
`desc` varchar(80),
`url` varchar(255),
`suburls` varchar(255)
    )";

    if(mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){
       echo "Success.";
    }

    else{

       echo "Error - ". mysqli_error($connect);

    }
```

Comment: -1: Missed the point entirely.

Comment: I missed one point, ok. @LightnessRacesinOrbit Raptor got the other. So Raptor didn't mention it, does he deserve a DV too?

Comment: No because the problem you describe is not the one that results in the OP's error message. It's a different problem. In a different _language_, even!!

Comment: It's still part of the problem @LightnessRacesinOrbit Table creation is entirely possible from within a script as such.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've fixed the OP's table creation issue. I'm not asking you to remove your DV, that's your opinion and you're entitled to it and I'll respect that.

Comment: You're welcome @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I admit I made a mistake and that I should have been more careful. I had overlooked the omission of `mysqli_query()` pointed out by Raptor, which is why I wanted to give the OP a functional piece of code, as the intention for the project, *cheers* - and thank you too, for having me see the errors of my ways.

Answer (score 5):

Your PHP has obvious syntax errors. You can't write a SQL in your PHP directly. You have to execute the query with functions like `mysqli_query()`. Also, if error occurs, your syntax still allows the script continues to run.

For the syntax of `mysqli_query()`, read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Comment: ah yes, good point. I guess it's a mix of both of our answers. +1

Comment: Something like this `$query = 'CREATE TABLE 
web_matrix
(
_title varchar(30),
\`desc\` varchar(80),
url varchar(255),
suburls varchar(255)
);' mysqli_query($query);`

Comment: Yes, but it's better to check the return value of the `mysqli_query()` function